# trim() function in Python using Flask

Tags: python, flask, trim

Is there a function like trim() in python?

i use Flask miniframework and it doesn't accept:

`selected_student = (request.args.get('student_form')).strip()`

its error:    `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

---

`selected_student.replace(" ", "")`

its error:     `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`

---

i need a function like trim() without coding a class/subclass or  javascript

Comment: `request.args.get('student_form')` returned `None`, not a string, because the field `student_form` is not there. You could return a default `''` instead with `request.args.get('student_form', '')` but you probably should check why the field is not there in the first place.

Comment: How are you sending your form data to your Flask file? Could you add an example to clarify how you're doing this?

Comment: @AJC24 
 `<form action="student" method='POST'>    
   <select name="student_form ">
    {% for student in students_list %}
     <option value="{{student}}">{{student}}</option> {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
  </form>`and here is .py:`... with app.open_resource('static/docs/student3.txt') as f3:
       content3 = f3.read()...`
   and:
   `... elif (selected_student == students_list[3]):
      content_selected = content3 ...`
        
i delete smthing, i think its clear. and i'm not sure is there any blank character in form data...

Comment: Just pointing this out - but you have a possible typo in your `form action="student"`. Your `action` should be a URL and should read as `/student`.

I assume you've set up your Flask server to include the route `/student`, then, too?

Comment: Yeah, that's rigth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the errors that you are seeing because there is **no data** being passed from your form to the Flask server. Your use of `request` is returning a `None` value type as opposed to a `str`.

You posted the following HTML mark up for your form:

```
<form action="/student" method='POST'>
    <select name="student_form ">
        {% for student in students_list %}
            <option value="{{student}}">{{student}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

So therefore you're going to need somewhere for Flask to pick up this data on the server side, for example:

```
@app.route('/student', methods=['POST'])
def receive_student_form_data:
    my_selection = str(request.form.get('student_form')).strip()
    print(my_selection)
```

Just to clarify why I've made my method in this way: I notice that you're using `request.args.get()` in order to retrieve the value sent by the form. This is incorrect.

`request.args` is used to retrieve key / value pairs from the URL.
`request.form` is used to retrieve key / value pairs from a HTML form.

So I'd suggest that you should use `request.form.get('student_form')` instead. If you really want to be certain that it is being cast as a `str` when retrieved by your Flask server, then you can cast it as a `str` as follows:

```
str(request.form.get('student_form'))
```

Then, as has been suggested by a few people already, you can use the `.strip()` method to remove any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **strip()** method. The error you get is because you are trying to run it on a *NoneType* object. You need to run it on a string object.

```
>>> s = 'some string   '
>>> s.strip()
'some string'
```

There is also replace for strings:

```
>>> s.replace('some', 'many')
'many string   '
```

The issue you encounter is related to something else. You end with a None object instead of what you are trying to get.

Comment: in my project there is an error when i use strip() -> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: This will emphasize what I mean. Run this code first: `selected_student = (request.args.get('student_form'))` and then try to `print selected_student` to get a print what the object is.

Comment: i tried `content_selected = 'Printing file is failed'.strip();` but it doesn't work... and i tried `print selected_student` it doesn't print....

Comment: You don't need to put `;` at the end of the statement in python

Comment: i forgot it, sorry :)